# Kendo Grid Server side filtering with a array type column

Tags: filter, server, kendo-grid, odata

I have this kendo grid blinded to my web service. One of the columns has a custom filter with a kendo multiselector array so the client can choose multiple ItemTypes. The grid is displaying data correctly but my costume filters are not working for this particular column. I got this error from the service: **"A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.ClinicFinder.Clinic.ItemType.ItemType' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind 'Equal'."**

My grid definition

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    type: "odata-v4",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function () {                    
                return "//myservice/api/clinics?$select=Id,Title,Address,ItemType,productsystems&top=20";
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Title: { type: "string" },
                CountryCode: { type: "string" },
                Street: { type: "string" },
                City: { type: "string" },
                Zip: { type: "string" },
                ItemType: { type: "" } 


            }
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,        
    serverSorting: false,
    pageSize: 20
},
pageable: true,
filterable: {
    mode: "row",
    extra: false,
    showOperators: false,
    operators: {
        string: {
            contains: "contains"
        }
    }
},
sortable: false,
columns: [
    { field: "Title", title: "Clinic" },
    { field: "CountryCode", title: "Country" },
    { field: "Street", title: "Address" },
    { field: "City", title: "City"  },
    { field: "Zip", title: "Zip",  filterable: false },       
    { field: "ItemType", title: "Clinic Type", filterable: { multi: true } }
],
rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html())    

});
```

My Filter function

```
function filterByclinicCategory() {
var filter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
var filterValue = $("#clinicTypeFilter").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
var clinicCode = [];
if (filterValue.length > 0) {
    $.each(filterValue, function (i, v) {
        clinicCode.push(convertClinicTypesInCodes(v));
        filter.filters.push({
            field: "ItemType", operator: "eq", value: clinicCode, logic: "or"
        });
        grid.dataSource.filter(filter);    
    });

} else {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
}


}
```

ItemType is the column I can´t filter.

My webservice data

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://sf-admin-local.medel.com/api/wstest/$metadata#clinics(*)",
"value": [
{
"Id": "896aa08b-2f17-64e6-80bd-ff09000c6e28",
"LastModified": "2019-05-13T09:28:04Z",
"PublicationDate": "2018-06-19T14:19:13Z",
"DateCreated": "2018-06-19T14:19:13Z",
"UrlName": "??",
"Email": "",
"URL": "",
"Telephone": "",
"Title": "????????",
"officeregions": [],
"salespartnerregions": [],
"productsystems": [
"b8ec2a8b-2f17-64e6-80bd-ff09000c6e28",
"1878cb61-ac79-69d9-867b-ff01007297b6",
"1b78cb61-ac79-69d9-867b-ff01007297b6",
"36d8938b-2f17-64e6-80bd-ff09000c6e28"
],
"Area": "",
"Order": 0,
"Tags": [],
"AdditionalInformation": "",
"ImportID": 1,
"Featured": false,
"ItemType": "2",
"Address": {
"Id": "d76aa08b-2f17-64e6-80bd-ff09000c6e28",
"CountryCode": "AT",
"StateCode": "",
"City": "????",
"Zip": "6800",
"Street": "Carinagasse ?????",
"Latitude": 47.2311043,
"Longitude": 9.580079999999953,
"MapZoomLevel": 8
}
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix it using **parameterMap** https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap.

I add a **parameterMap: functiondata, type)** function, with that I was able to intercept and change the call made by the filters.

```
 parameterMap: function (data, type) {               
     var c = kendo.data.transports["odata-v4"].parameterMap(data, type);
     if (c.$filter) {
     //my transformation
     c = myTransformation;
     return c;
     } else{
     return c; //not apply transformation loading the data
     }

 }
```